# Glasgow to London by rail

Tags: england

Anyone have any tips (NOT links to websites) for a 2 or 3 day rail trip from Glasgow to London? Preferably the Midlands and Cotswolds.

Comment: I am sorry but we really don't do travel itineraries and recommendations on Travel.SE. [You might want to read the help centre](http://travel.stackexchange.com/help). Voting to close.

Comment: "Tips" is extremely open-ended, and our format is designed to identify a single definitive answer, rather than a list of possibilities. If you have a specific question about the journey, however, we may be able to assist.